# Changing type of primary key when you have foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a table with elements :

```
SGA
----
Pk | Integer (PRIMARY KEY)

and it has 3 - 4 relations
SB1
----
FK1 | Integer (references PK)


SB1
----
FK1 | Integer (references PK)


SB2
----
FK2 | Integer (references PK)


SB3
----
FK3 | Integer (references PK)
```

I want to change the type of PK to text but it gives a constrain error (which is obvious). Is there a SQL command, so that I can reflect the changes on the other tables as well.

The database has no values in it as of now and is the database is constructed.

Comment: I think the only way to achieve this is to re-build the tables from scratch and populate them with the existing data. Anyway, the information you have provided does not make sense. Can you show the actual schema of the relations/tables?

Comment: yes. I also think the same.
Another alternative maybe to remove the constraints, change the types and add the constraints again. I am not sure which one will be better though

Comment: @manugupt1 yes, i just wanted to write that (to drop FKs then re-create them after the type changes): PostgreSQL can handle DDL statements in a transaction https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL:_A_Competitive_Analysis

Comment: Ah.. Thanks I did not know that Transactions in Postgres can handle DDL, which is great!!!

Answer (score 3):

You have to update each table explicitly like this, there is no shortcut SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE child DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name ;
ALTER TABLE child ALTER COLUMN fk_col TYPE new_type;
ALTER TABLE parent ALTER COLUMN pk_col TYPE new_type;
ALTER TABLE child ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name 
    FOREIGN KEY fk_col REFERENCES parent(pk_col);
```

eg:

```
create temp table foo( i integer primary key);
create temp table bar ( foo_i integer references foo(i) );
insert into foo values (1),(2),(3);
insert into bar values (1),(2),(2);

ALTER TABLE bar DROP CONSTRAINT bar_foo_i_fkey;
ALTER TABLE bar ALTER COLUMN foo_i TYPE text USING 'NUM:'||foo_i;
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN i     TYPE text USING 'NUM:'||i;
ALTER TABLE bar ADD CONSTRAINT bar_foo_i_fkey
    FOREIGN KEY (foo_i) REFERENCES foo(i);
```

`USING` is optional, only needed if you want to do some sort of translation when changing types, or if postgres doesn't know how to translate them.